What does being prone do in Shadowrun fifth edition?
What benefits and restrictions does being prone apply to a character?
I first came across this question when an enemy used suppressive fire against my group. The rules say you can drop prone in response as a free action. However, there is no one section that seems to denote what all 'being prone' entails. From what the group found, it imposes some penalties to attacking and defending, but we only found those thanks to a cheat-sheet for combat someone had. Even that did not mention how being prone impacts movement, something my group could not find reference to.
So, for the sake of a complete answer and assuming I've missed something, I'm asking for a complete list of the modifiers at play when a character is prone in Shadowrun 5e.

The rules are scattered throughout the book, and there's a bunch of them. I'll summarize first, give sources second.
Summary

If you are not surprised, You may Drop Prone as a Free Action, or as an Interrupt Action (costing 5 Initiative) if you already used your Free Action
Rising from Prone is a Simple Action, but requires a Body + Willpower (2) Test if you are wounded (wound modifiers apply)
If you are prone, you are immune to suppressive fire
If you try to make a melee attack while prone, -1 to your attack dice pool
If you try to make a melee attack against a prone target, +1 to your attack dice pool
If you are prone and someone attacks you, either in melee or from within 5 meters, -2 to your defense dice pool (Yes, this stacks with the item above)
If you are prone and more than 20 meters away from your attacker, count as having Good Cover (+4 do your defense dice pool)
Cannot Intercept
Subdued characters are considered Prone for the purpose of resolving attacks
Some items (just one in the CRB) may have modifiers that apply when Prone, such as a Bipod, which (when prone) gives you 2 points of Recoil Compensation.

Noteworthy Exclusion
I have checked the Core Rulebook as well as Run & Gun (the main combat expansion rulebook) and Run Faster (the character expansion rulebook) and there are no rules pertaining to movement while Prone. Nor can I recall encountering such rules anywhere else in all the books I've read.
Sources
Drop Prone - Core Rulebook p.164

A character may kneel or drop prone as a Free Action, as long as he is not surprised. A character who is surprised may not drop prone.

Rise from Prone - Core Rulebook p. 166

Using a Simple Action, a character who is lying down or prone may stand up. If the character is wounded and attempting to stand, he must succeed in a Body + Willpower (2) Test to do so (wound modifiers apply to this test).

Hit the Dirt - Core Rulebook p.168

Interrupt Action, -5 Initiative:
A character who has already used their Free Action may choose to drop prone when caught by suppressive fire using this action. The defending character doesn't need to make the Reaction + Edge test but is considered prone on their next Action Phase. If the suppressive fire continues, the defending character needs to use a Stand Up Simple Action to get back up, risking getting shot, or fight from the ground. If the suppressive fire has stopped the prone character still needs to use a Stand Up Simple Action to get back up.

Suppressive Fire - Core Rulebook p.179

[...] Any character who is in the suppressed area (but not behind cover or prone), or who moves into or out of the area before the end of the suppressive fire, risks catching some flying lead.

Melee Attack Modifiers, Attacker Prone - Core Rulebook p.187

you suffer a -1 dice pool penalty to melee attacks

Melee Attack Modifiers, Opponent Prone - Core Rulebook p.187

Attacker gains a +1 dice pool bonus

Defense Modifier, Defender Prone - Core Rulebook p.189

Characters who are on the ground have a more difficult time getting out of the way and suffer a -2 dice pool modifier. This modifier does not apply to defending against ranged attacks unless the attacker is extremely close (5 meters or less)

Defender/Target has good cover Core Rulebook p.190

If the Defender uses a Take Cover action to get behind something where more than 50% of the defender's body is obscured by intervening terrain or cover, he gains a +4 dice pool modifier to his Defense roll against any attack. This modifier can also apply to prone targets that are at least twenty meters away from their attackers.

Interception Core Rulebook p.194

Prone combatants cannot intercept

Subduing Core Rulebook p.195

Consider the subdued character to be prone for any attacks made against him.

Bipod Core Rulebook p.431

This two-legged brace extends downward from the weapon, allowing it to be fired low to the ground with the user in a prone or sitting position. [...] provides 2 points of Recoil Compensation when properly deployed.


Very helpful answer; Pertaining to movement, is there anything you know of in the movement rules that would suggest being prone would prevent movement? Or is it more likely that movement within this system is abstract enough that it's safe to assume being prone does not hinder movement? Given how much of a hindrance being prone seems to be in this system, I'm inclined to say house ruling in a penalty to movement-while more realistic-is not necessary for balance, assuming it's allowed at all.

@Necroes Unfortunately, it seems more like an oversight that they left it out. Movement in the system is not abstract, it is very "crunchy" like pretty much everything else in SR5. Your movement is calculated based on your Metatype and Agility, that movement is shared across the entire Combat Turn (potentially multiple Initiative passes), and movement is broken up into walk/run/sprint with detailed rules for all three. At least when I ran SR5 a few years ago, I personally felt the need to houserule it in

@Necroes when it comes to movement, there are detailed rules for climbing, rappelling, jumping, swimming, diving (which is separated from swimming), treading water, and more. But no rules for crawling.
